# Coloring lines with polygon grid using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology

In Arcgis, I have a polygon grid layer (100 cells) and a layer with polylines (the polylines cross the polygon grid). The polygon grid layer has in the attribute table a numeric integer field (named "weight") that give to the respective cell a weight. Example:
cell1-->100
cell2-->105
cell3-->2
cell4-->27 
cell5-->3
...-->...
cell100-->89

my goal is ONLY purely visual nothing more. I want color each cell of the the polygon grid with a color based on the weight attribute (clearly if weight of cells is almost equal I want use similar color). After (this is the main problem) I want that only a part of each polyline take the color of the cell that cross. So the final view of each polyline will be N-polyline with multiple gradient color. The intersect tool isn't a good solution because in real case I have a lot of polyline and a lot of cells, so the intersection process is very slow.

[image]

Comment: What version/extensions are you using? there may be additional tools you could use in more recent versions

Comment: I use arcgis 10.3

Answer (score 1):

You need to use intersect tool from `ArcToolboxes->Analysis tools->Overlay->Intersect` in ArcGIS to intersect the polygon grid with polyline.

[image]

Then use the field "Weight" that will output after applying the intersection to classify the polyline and the polygon grid with the same symbology color.

Comment: This is not a good solution because I have a lot of polyline and a lot of cells, in this case the intersect process is very slow.

Comment: Then you can use spatial join to join the attribute table of the polyline with polygon spatially, and use Intersection as a spatial method.

Comment: can you describe me the steps?

Comment: I updated my answer. However, I prefer the intersect tool as it will cut the polyline into smaller one based on each polygon grid.

Comment: Sorry, Spatial join will not work as it should cut each line with each polygon grid and the spatial join will not do that.

Comment: something wrong. First solution is a true solution but I can't use it because the process time to intersect is almost infinite. Second solution has some issue because all atribute are join in the polyline layer. Now the polyline take different color but NOT the single part of each polyline.
Edit: see your answer late...so there isn't a good solution...

Comment: Convert the polygron grid to raster can be a solution? steps?

Comment: The only option you have is to use intersect tool. May be it is not efficient for your data, but you will get correct results.

Comment: I can't believe that is the only one solution. I mean...we talk about how to color not a complex problem :( . In adobe after effects it's possible for example make a difference of image and similar options to process the image overlap. How can is possible that arcgis don't provide this kind of method...

Answer (score 0):

If the Intersect tool is unable to process the whole task, you may need to break the steps up. so break the polylines first, then join them. 
1)Breaking up the lines: If you are using 10.0 or later with advanced licence, you could try the Split tool to divide the polylines, or the Identity tool. Also, you could convert the polygon cells into polylines, merge this with the original polyline layer (ensure you have a field that will let you filter them back out again), and use the Topology tool 'Planarize Lines' to break up the lines. delete all the cell border polylines from the dataset, and you'll have a fully segmented set of polylines that you can join to the corresponding cells.

If your goal is purely visual, you could work with symbology instead to get the desired effect. Select a line style that has a wide middle and two edge lines (the default 'Double, Plain' for example, doesn't even have a middle line, just edges) and set the color to 'No Color'. you'll have an edged line that shows the underlying polygon color
see below the resulting appearance
[image: hollow highway lines]

Comment: my goal is ONLY purely visual nothing more. Can you explain better the steps for use symbology?

Comment: I try to use "Freeway" with no color in polyline layer (the polyline layer is above the polygon grid layer). The result was polyline become all black and doesn't take the color of the underlying polygon color

Comment: Oops, maybe try 'double, plain', the way 'freeway' is drawn uses a wider black line under a coloured line, instead of two offset lines to make the edge. the idea is to make a 'hollow' line to show the underlying colours

Comment: open the polyline layer properties, click the symbology tab, click the 'symbol' button, and scroll or search to find 'Double, Plain'. click OK, and OK, and that's it